# Using vba to automate clicking button on website

Tags: vba

I am trying to use vba to navigate to a website, login and make a selection in a dropdown box. I am stuck on making a selection in a drop down box. To view the dropdown you must click an icon button and then click the selection which is a export to csv option. I believe that the icon button is called rallybutton-1175, the dropdown menu that appears is rallymenu-1225 and the option I would like to select in the dropdown is menuitem-1227. The page itself is very complex and does not have a simple refernce to the button like a submit button..

I have tried several things to click these "buttons"..

```
  doc.getElementById("rallymenu-1225").selectedindex=1
  doc.getElementById("rallymenu-1225").FireEvent("onchange")
```

and

```
  Call objIE.document.parentWindow.execScript("menduitem-1227", "JavaScript").Click
```

and

```
      With .document
     ' select action menu
       Set dropDownMenu = .getElementsByID("rallymenu-1225")
      Set dropDownMenu(1) = "menuitem-1227"

            End With
```

and

```
      Call objIE.document.parentWindow.execScript("menduitem-1219", "JavaScript").Click
```

and

```
             'click action menu icon
            Set htmlDoc = .document
            Set htmlColl = htmlDoc.getElementById("rallybutton-1175-btnIconEl")
            Do While htmlDoc.readyState <> "complete": DoEvents: Loop
                For Each htmlInput In htmlColl
                    If Trim(htmlInput.ID) = "rallybutton-1175-btnIconEl" Then
                        htmlInput.Click
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next htmlInput
```

The following is code I can share...

```
   <div id="rallymenu-1225" class="x4-panel rally-menu no-icon x4-layer x4-panel-default x4-menu x4-menu-plain x4-border-box" style="width: 148px; height: 73px; right: auto; left: 1090px; top: 148px; z-index: 19001;"   tabindex="-1"> 
  <div id="rallymenu-1225-body" class="x4-panel-body x4-menu-body x4-unselectable x4-panel-body-default x4-box-layout-ct x4-panel-body-default" role="presentation" style="width: 148px; height: 73px; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
 <div class="x4-box-inner x4-box-scroller-top x4-box-scroller-plain" role="presentation">
 <div id="rallymenu-1225-before-scroller" class="x4-box-scroller x4-menu-scroll-top" style="display:none" role="presentation"></div>
<div id="rallymenu-1225-innerCt" class="x4-box-inner x4-vertical-box-overflow-  body" role="presentation" style="height: 73px; width: 148px;">
<div id="x4-gen1922" class="x4-menu-icon-separator" role="presentation"> </div>
<div id="rallymenu-1225-targetEl" class="x4-box-target" role="presentation"   style="width: 148px;">
<div id="menuitem-1226" class="x4-component x4-box-item x4-component-default x4-    menu-item" style="right: auto; left: 0px; top: 0px; margin: 0px;">
<div id="menuitem-1227" class="x4-component x4-box-item x4-component-default x4-   menu-item" style="right: auto; left: 0px; top: 25px; margin: 0px; width:   148px;">
<a id="menuitem-1227-itemEl" class="x4-menu-item-link " unselectable="on" hidefocus="true" role="presentation" href="#">
<span id="menuitem-1227-textEl" class="x4-menu-item-text" unselectable="on">Export to CSV...</span>
```

I've also posted this question here...http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=195757

Thank you!

Comment: any chance of sharing the webpage?

Comment: Did you try: objIE.doc.getElementById("rallymenu-1225").click() or objIE.doc.getElementById("rallymenu-1225").checked = True to click the button. The option to select the dropdown could be as simple as objIE.doc.getElementById("DROPDOWN").value = "YourValue".

Comment: Hi Miss Palmer, the website in question requires a license and credentials to access. I cannot give out that information unfortunately.. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Ryan, I tried each of these but I keep getting "Object doesn't support this property or method". I am using these to work with the buttons if this helps...  'code'   Dim objIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer 'microsoft internet controls (shdocvw.dll)
    Dim htmlDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument 'Microsoft HTML Object Library
    Dim htmlInput As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
    Dim htmlColl As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection 'code'  Thank you!

Comment: I tried "scraping" Rally with VBA. It is a huge investment of time and if they change the data model at all, your code will break. Have you tried iMacros? http://imacros.net/overview  It would be a bit more "bullet proof" and you can get it working in less time.

Comment: Hi Steve, I came to the same conclusion. I didn't get support on getting an imacros license and the same brittleness was there--if Rally changes anything it would break. I ended up doing a semi manual extraction and then setting up an SSIS job to import into a database built for this purpose. My goal is that overtime this database will be data rich and can be used to get the additional reporting I was needing. Thank you for looking into it.